# What if there are no rows returned in a foreach loop from a database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Problem: Everytime I loop an empty row, it says:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
//return results from `users` table.
$users = DB::getInstance()->get('users');

//loop the username from the users table
foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user['username'] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: The only issue you would face is that $users may not be an array (may error or notice), passing an empty array to foreach simply does nothing

Comment: It seems like you are using an ORM or some form of database library. Got a name or some code for us to look at?

Comment: if there's no rows, then presumably `$users` would be an empty array, and the foreach would simply not do anything.

Comment: You should really investigate why `get()` is returning something other than an empty array when there are no rows. That seems to be a bad design.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing which database library you are using, you could do something like this to check if any users were returned.

```
if (is_array($users) && count($users) > 0) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user['username'] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

If you provide more details I will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: There's no need to test `count($users)`. If the count is 0, the loop will just stop immediately.

Comment: @Barmar That is correct, but the question title is "What if there are no rows returned", so I gave a way to check if any rows actually were returned.